# LINQ for nested for each

Tags: linq

Can you please give me a solution for the method as Linq?

I need Linq for the below method:

```
private List<Model> ConvertMethod(List<Model> List1, List<Model> List2)
{
    foreach (var Firstitem in List1)
    {
        foreach (var Seconditem in List2)
        {
            if (Firstitem.InnerText.Trim() == Seconditem.InnerText.Trim())
            {
                Seconditem.A= Firstitem.A;
                Seconditem.B= Firstitem.B;
                Seconditem.C= Firstitem.C;
                Seconditem.D= Firstitem.D;
                Seconditem.E= Firstitem.E;
                Seconditem.F= Firstitem.F;
            }

        }
    }
    return List2;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? We're not a code writing service.

Comment: Why exactly do you 'need Linq'? Does the code snippet work as desired?

Comment: And to the person who upvoted this question, could you explain why you think this is useful and shows research effort?

Comment: LINQ is a functional query language, its purpose is to **query** data, not to produce side effects. You want to change the content of `List2`, that's not what linq is for.

Answer (score 1):

Your task is to assign values, so modify objects. That's not the purpose of LINQ which is to query datasources. So you could use LINQ to build a query that returns all items that need to be updated. Then you can use a `foreach` to assign the values(as you did):

```
var sameItems = from l1 in List1 join l2 in List2 
                on l1.InnerText.Trim() equals l2.InnerText.Trim()
                select new { l1, l2 };
foreach(var itemsToUpdate in sameItems)
{
    itemsToUpdate.l2.A = itemsToUpdate.l1.A;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It helps if you think about what this code is supposed to do - update records in the second list with the values of matching records from the first list.

There are various ways you can do that. One option is to replace each `foreach` with `from` and filter the rows:

```
var matches = from var Firstitem in List1
              from var Seconditem in List2
              where Firstitem.InnerText.Trim() == Seconditem.InnerText.Trim()
              select (Firstitem,Seconditem);

foreach(var (Firstitem,Seconditem) in matches)
{
     Seconditem.A= Firstitem.A;
     Seconditem.B= Firstitem.B;
     Seconditem.C= Firstitem.C;
     Seconditem.D= Firstitem.D;
     Seconditem.E= Firstitem.E;
     Seconditem.F= Firstitem.F;
}
```

I'm "cheating" a bit here, using tuples and decomposition to reduce noise

Another option is to use `join`. In this case, the two options are identical :

```
var matches = from Firstitem in List1
              join Seconditem in List2
              on  Firstitem.InnerText.Trim() equals Seconditem.InnerText.Trim()
              select (Firstitem,Seconditem);
```

The rest of the code remains the same